# keras predict_proba return values higher than 1

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am using LSTM for binary classification therefore my last dense layer looks like that:

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

I want to get the probability for each input but

```
model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

return values bigger than 1. I understand that it because I didnt use 'softmax' in the last layer but at binary classification I have to use sigmoid yet how can I could get probabilities range [0,1]?

the values I get now is:

```
array([[1.1198873e-07],
       [1.1001220e-07],
       [7.2163729e-08],
       ...,
       [1.1758399e-09],
       [1.6062747e-10],
       [1.5407189e-11]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What exact values are you getting?

Comment: I edit the question and add the values

Comment: I think you need to learn what is scientific notation...

Comment: none of the values are larger than 1, at the end of each value you can see, e-07, which mean it is 10 ^ -7, which is 0.0000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values are not above one. This is scientific notation.
`1.1198873e-07 = 1.1198873/10,000,000 = 0.00000011198873`
So these are actually far below 1.